# Animating in an element created with Renderer2

Tags: angular, animation

I'm using Angular 4.2.5 and I'm looking for a way to animate in an element created with `Renderer2`. Previously, with `Renderer`, there was a function `.animate()`, but that's not the case now. Let's say I have the following directive:

```
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, Renderer2, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[text-content]'
})
export class TextContentDirective {
  @Input('text-content') textContent: string;
  box: ElementRef;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2 ) { }

  @HostListener('mouseenter', ['$event.target'])
  mouseEnter(target) {
    this.box = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    let span = this.renderer.createElement('span');
    let content = this.renderer.createText(this.textContent);
    this.renderer.appendChild(span, content);
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.box, span);
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.element.nativeElement, this.box);
  }
}
```

And the HTML

```
<div [text-content]="Hello World">Hover me</div>
```

The element is created and added to the `div` when I hover `div`, but how can I make it appear with an animation? It might be possible by adding a class to the generated `div`. But it can't be done too quickly, otherwise the animation won't fire. I'm looking for a way to do it with `@angular/animations`.

Comment: did you try official documentation? [Angular 4 animations](https://angular.io/guide/animations). Now animations are not in the Renderer2 since Angular team introduced a platform independent layer.

Comment: @ShanilFernando It's more about animating components rather than animating elements

Comment: did you try with CSS3 Transitions?

Comment: See this post - all the way at the bottom - 8.0 Programmatic Animations with AnimationBuilder. Its the only way to do it with the animations API  -->  https://www.yearofmoo.com/2017/06/new-wave-of-animation-features.html

Answer (score 0):

I did not test this, but I just wanted to give you an idea to try

```
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, Renderer2, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[text-content]'
})
export class TextContentDirective {
  @Input('text-content') textContent: string;
  box: ElementRef;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2 ) {
    this.box = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    // Added
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.box,"opacity",0);
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.box,"transition","opacity 2s");
    //
    let span = this.renderer.createElement('span');
    let content = this.renderer.createText(this.textContent);
    this.renderer.appendChild(span, content);
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.box, span);
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.element.nativeElement, this.box);
 }

  @HostListener('mouseenter', ['$event.target'])
  mouseEnter(target) {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.box,"opacity",1);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
Try this

```
     import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, Renderer2, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

        @Directive({
          selector: '[text-content]'
        })
        export class TextContentDirective {
          @Input('text-content') textContent: string;
          box: ElementRef;

          constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2 ) {

         }

          @HostListener('mouseenter', ['$event.target'])
          mouseEnter(target) {
            this.box = this.renderer.createElement('div');
            // Added
            this.renderer.setStyle(this.box,"opacity",0);
            this.renderer.setStyle(this.box,"transition","opacity 2s");
            //
            let span = this.renderer.createElement('span');
            let content = this.renderer.createText(this.textContent);
            this.renderer.appendChild(span, content);
            this.renderer.appendChild(this.box, span);
            this.renderer.appendChild(this.element.nativeElement, this.box);
            this.renderer.setStyle(this.box,"opacity",1);
          }
        }
```

Comment: Something like this should work, but I was looking for a way to animate it as it is created. Now you're creating all the boxes first, and then only adding/removing a class to them when hovering.

Comment: " Now you're creating all the boxes first, and then only adding/removing a class to them when hovering"  YES, I intentionally do it for more performance gain. Think about why do you need to create the same content every time he is hovering if the content are same?

Comment: Sure, I know it could be a better way to render them at init, in this case. But there might be situations where you don't want to render an element/a bunch of elements at page init

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a style class in setTimeout:

```
// animate this.box element
this.box = this.renderer.createElement('div');
this.renderer.addClass(this.box, 'my-class');
setTimeout(() => this.renderer.addClass(this.box, 'my-class-visible'));
...
```

styles.css:

```
/* Animate height */
.my-class {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: all 1000ms;
}
.my-class-visible {
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking the example in the OP, I was able to add a simple [animation trigger](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers) to a newly created element with renderer2 using the following:

```
this.renderer.setProperty(this.box, '@myAnimationTrigger', 'true');
```